# how to subtract same column of row where type is different?

Tags: php, mysql, accounting

I want to subtract rows of same table where (where clause is different ).

```
SELECT SUM(`balance`) AS `balance` FROM `vouchers`  WHERE `type`='CP' AND `post_status`='yes' GROUP BY `interactive_person`;
```

the above query give me desirable result for first kinda rows! the second query is

```
SELECT SUM(`balance`) AS `balance` FROM `vouchers`  WHERE `type`='CR' AND `post_status`='yes' GROUP BY `interactive_person`;
```

These query return more then one row grouped by interactive person i want that it subtract record where interactive person(is a number) is same but type is change. in short its like CashReceipt - CashPayment. I used first query as a subquery of second but error shown that subquery return more then one row. i need help to solve this !

Comment: may b you looking for where_in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `case` to calculate your `sum()` in same query

```
SELECT 
SUM(CASE WHEN `type`='CP' THEN `balance` ELSE 0 END) AS CP_balance,
SUM(CASE WHEN `type`='CR' THEN `balance` ELSE 0 END) AS CR_balance,
SUM(CASE WHEN `type`='CP' THEN `balance` WHEN `type`='CR' THEN  -1 * `balance` ELSE 0 END) AS diff
FROM `vouchers`  
WHERE `post_status`='yes' 
GROUP BY `interactive_person`;
```

Comment: yeah i was looking for this type query and it was helpful although you forgot comma "," after CR_balance but still it solve my problem even tho i was searching for its solution from two days

Comment: @ArsalanAfridi Glad it helped you, +1 for highlighting syntax issue